# How to get the selected index of my tabbarcontroller inside the related viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Hey Guys i want to get the selected index of my `UITabbarController` inside the related `UIViewControllers`.
I tried to get the `parentViewController` with `[self parentViewController];` But it seems , this isnt the right way, because the controller i get back does not no a method like `selectedIndex` or so. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I found a solution : NSInteger selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the tabBarController's `selectedIndex` property

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    int i = [self.tabBarController selectedIndex];
    NSLog(@"Selected Index = %d",i);
```

Comment: If i select the tab at index 0 i got the number 2147483647. Does it have to do anything with the right format ?

Comment: here when you click on any tab at that time it return previous viewcontroler tag value... like if u r in 2 tab and u select 1 tab at that time above code return Selected index = 2..

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do that. Imagine that you have 4 icons in the `TabBarcontroller`. If you want to access any of them, you have to do as it follows:

```
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

The index is the position in the tabBar